# Ошибка при обращении к TSensorManager.Current внутри события POSIX-таймера

Tags: android, delphi, многопоточность, геолокация, radstudio

```
Uses AndroidApi.Timer, System.Sensors;
```

Я не хочу, чтобы GPS датчик садил аккумулятор, поэтому в своем Android сервисе использую POSIX таймер (AndroidTimerCreate), чтобы в его событии время от времени включать и выключать LocationSensor. Для меня приемлемо собирать координаты устройства раз в 5 минут.

Когда я обращаюсь к свойству TSensorManager.Current,

```
TSensorManager.Current.Activate;
FSensors := SensorManager.Current.GetSensorsByCategory(TSensorCategory.Location);
```

получаю ошибку

> Сan't start sensor: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Если я выполняю этот код в основном потоке, например, в событиях AndroidServiceStartCommand или AndroidServiceCreate, то SensorManager отлично активируется.

Для теста проблемы перенес код из сервиса в Multi-Device Appplication — проблема осталась.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как включать и выключать LocationSensor по событию таймера (ну или просто раз в 5 минут)?

Comment: Написано же: `thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`. Логично предположить, что нужно предварительно сделать вызов `Looper.prepare()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел такое решение:

1. Создаю для LocalBroadcastManager фильтр на действие 'ACTION_LOCATION_CHANGE' и регистрирую LocalBroadcastReceiver;
2. В событии таймера отправляю sendBroadcast действие 'ACTION_LOCATION_CHANGE';
3. В обработчике LocalBroadcastReceiver переключаю активность TLocationSensor.

Подсмотрел [решение здесь](http://www.gesource.jp/weblog/?p=7270), очень хороший пример.